# application.run with variables set within run method function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro with variables as follows:

```
Range("A1").Application.Run (SetConditionalFormatingSub,ConditionB="=""O-BETTER-T-PRV""",ConditionW = "=""O-WORSE-T-PRV""",ConditionM = "=""O-MIXED-T-PRV""")
```

But I get an error as follows: 
Compile error
Expected =

Still a novice in excel coding, can't figure out what seems to be the problem.

Hopefully you guys can help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Range("A1").Application.Run "SetConditionalFormatingSub", "='O-BETTER-T-PRV'", "='O-WORSE-T-PRV'", "='O-MIXED-T-PRV'"
```

Notes:

- don't use parentheses () when calling a sub;
- you can't use names for sub parameters (like ConditionW) with Run method - it only accepts arguments by position (the same order they are defined in your macro);
- you can't use quotes inside quotes. Instead, use single quotes, for example " 'Hello' ", instead of " "Hello" "
- I don't think you need an Application.Run method for your task. You can set conditional formatting for your range directly using FormatConditions.Add method:

[FormatConditions.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822801.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot with my other macros as well.

Comment: I've never heard of a restriction on the characters able to be used in a string variable before, even when passed to a subroutine via `Application.Run`.  (In fact I just tried `Application.Run "xyz", "a is ""a"""` and the string was correctly passed through as `a is "a"`.)  So there should be no reason for the OP not to use parameters such as `"=""O-BETTER-T-PRV"""`